Undefined method 'following'. Intelephense P1013
Выдает ошибку о неизвестном методе, хотя в модели User определенна связь following.
Связь в модели User:
    public function following()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'follows', 'follower_id', 'followed_id');
        }

Метод в котором я получаю ошибку:
public function follow($userId)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        if (!$user) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Вы не авторизованы'], 401);
        }

        $userToFollow = User::findOrFail($userId);

        if ($user->id === $userToFollow->id) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Вы не можете подписаться на самого себя'], 400);
        }

        $user->following()->attach($userToFollow->id);

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Вы успешно подписались'], 200);
    }


Если речь об расширении PHP Intelephense для VS Code, а не реальной ошибке, то с Laravel он не всегда хорошо работает, по крайней мере так было раньше
